# How to do a token conversion?

Tags: solidity

I'm trying to write a contract that can take tokens of one type and send you the equivalent amount of the other. (two to one ratio) is there any way to do this with one transaction? as apposed to having the user approve the withdrawal from their wallet. my current code is showed below (still a noob to solidity).

```
function convertToUSD (uint _value ) external {
        uint bbdValue=_value*2;
        if (USDAddress.delegatecall(bytes32(keccak256("approve(address,value)")), this,_value)){
            if (USDToken.transferFrom(msg.sender,this,_value)){
                if (BBDToken.transfer(msg.sender,bbdValue)){}
                else {
                    revert();
                }
            }
            else{
                revert();
            }
        }
    }

    function convertToBBD (uint _value ) external {
        uint bbdValue=_value*2;
        if (BBDAddress.delegatecall(bytes32(keccak256("approve(address,value)")), this,bbdValue)){
            if (BBDToken.transferFrom(msg.sender,this,bbdValue)){
                if (USDToken.transfer(msg.sender,_value)){} 
                else {
                    revert();
                }
            }
            else{
                revert();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

With a standard ERC20 token, no, there's no way to avoid having two transactions: one to `approve` the transfer to the contract and one to `transferFrom` the spender.